# How to add smooth step equation to a shader node graph?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, mathematics

I'm trying to add some math to a shader network that I'm building.  I want to take a numeric output from a node and pipe it through the equation f(x) = -2x^3 + 3x^2 (this is sometimes called the smooth step equation).  While I could do this by dragging five Math nodes into the graph, this seems like a messy way to solve this.

Is there an easier way to add an equation like this to a graph?  Does Blender already have a smooth step node I could just use?

Comment: I just found the node grouping tools that the shader network provides.  This lets me hide all of those math nodes inside of a single node.

Comment: This still seems a bit messy given how useful & ubiquitous smoothstep is; if you end up implementing it with math nodes doing pow etc it could make the render quite a bit slower than it should be I'd imagine.  Actually it looks like a relevant change was comitted just shortly before you asked your question and now "Map Range" should do the trick.

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/D5827